# Ralink Bluetooth adapter is not detecting Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, ralink, 17.10

I have a problem with my ASUS k550DP and my integrated **Bluetooth Ralink device**, with Ubuntu 17.10, the `rfkill list all` command does not show me the Bluetooth device

```
yuliand@yuliand-X550DP:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
yuliand@yuliand-X550DP:~$ lspci
04:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

I have tried in many ways that I have found in forums but I do not manage to make it work, I appreciate your help